# How to click Javascript button using selenium and python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

Assume the following button is present on a page:

```
<input type="submit" name="next_btn" value="Next" onclick="gonext();" id="btnNext">
```

Additionally, when clicked manually, the page takes ~3-6 seconds to load and display new data.

I've tried respectively:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("next_btn").submit()
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_name("next_btn").click()
```

Neither does anything in this case, so I figured I could try and execute the `gonext()` JavaScript, only to be met by an attribute error as such: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'submit` - have also tried with `.click()`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are coding in Python, you should be doing:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_name('next_btn');
element.click();
```

Or you may use:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('btnNext');
element.click();
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: @yoshiserry You won't be clicking this same button with same  id multiple times in a real time _usecase_. Moreover attempting to click the  same button with same  id multiple times will raise [stalelementreferenceexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838538/staleelementreference-exception-in-pagefactory/44844879#44844879)

Comment: sorry the same button with the same name not _id

Comment: @yoshiserry I believe `name` attribute is also unique just like `id` attribute. Hence the similar logic applies as per my previous comment _you won't be clicking this same button with same id multiple times in a real time usecase. Moreover attempting to click the same button with same id multiple times will raise stalelementreferenceexception_.