# StaleElementReference Exception in PageFactory

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, page-factory, staleelementreferenceexception

I am trying to learn the PageFactory model. I understood the fact that when we do a `initElements`, the WebElements are located. Say for example, I click on a webelement and because of which there is a change in one of the other webelements in DOM. Now, obviously I would get a `StaleElementReferenceException` here. How would I resolve this issue?

Should I find that specific WebElement again knowing the fact that there can be a change in the WebElement's properties in the DOM? or is there an another way to handle this?

Comment: I recommend using this library, which solves the intermittent StaleElementReference exception and brings some enhancements to Selenium page Object model and Page Factory features:
https://github.com/fslev/selenium-jutils#retry-on-error

Answer (score 20):

### StaleElementReferenceException

[StaleElementReferenceException](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/StaleElementReferenceException.html) extends [WebDriverException](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriverException.html) and indicates that the previous reference of the element is now **stale** and the element reference is no longer present on the DOM of the page.

---

### Common Reasons

- The common reasons behind facing *`StaleElementReferenceException`* are as follows:

  - *The element has been deleted entirely.*
  - *The element is no longer attached to the DOM.*
  - *The webpage on which the element was part of has been refreshed.*
  - *The (previous) element has been deleted by a **JavaScript** or **AjaxCall** and is replaced by a (new) element with the same `ID` or other attributes.*
- Solution **:** If an (old) element has been replaced with new identical one, the simple strategy would be to use `findElement()` or `findElements` to look out for the element again.

---

### Answering your queries

1. *When we do a initElements, the WebElements are located* : When you call `initElements()` method, all the *WebElements* of that page will get initialized. For example,

   ```
   LoginPageNew login_page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPageNew.class);
   ```

   This line of code will initialize all the static *WebElements* defined within the scope of the `LoginPageNew.class` whenever and wherever it is invoked from your Automation Script.
2. *I click on a webelement and because of which there is a change in one of the other webelements in DOM* : This is pretty much possible.

   - As an example, in general invoking `click()` on a `<input>` tag wouldn't trigger any change of any of the *WebElements* on the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).
   - Where as invoking `click()` on a `<button>` tag or `<a>` tag may call a **JavaScript** or a **Ajax** which inturn may delete an element or can replace the (previous) element by a (new) element with the same `ID` or other attributes.

---

### Conclusion

So, if *WebDriver* throws a *StaleElementReferenceException*, that implies even though the element still exists, the reference is lost. We should discard the current reference we have and replace it by locating the *WebElement* once again when it gets attached to the DOM. That means you have to again reinitialize the class through `initElements()` method which inturn reinitializes all the *WebElements* defined in that page.

---

### Solution

If a old element has been replaced with new identical one, the simple strategy would be to invoke [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) inconjunction with [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) to look out for the element.

You can find relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to add explicit wait in PageFactory in PageObjectModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158166/how-to-add-explicit-wait-in-pagefactory-in-pageobjectmodel/54177337#54177337)

---

### References

Here are the references of this discussion:

- [Stale Element Reference Exception](https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp)
- [Class StaleElementReferenceException](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/StaleElementReferenceException.html)
- [Selenium: How to tell if RemoteWebDriver.findElements(By) can throw StaleElementReferenceException at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51419727/selenium-how-to-tell-if-remotewebdriver-findelementsby-can-throw-staleelement)

Comment: Actually, it's not necessary to reinitialize your page class.  it is sufficient to search for the specific element again.

Comment: The downvote is because you do not have to reinitialize the entire page.  As your quote from the documentation, and other answers, have mentioned, you can simply search for the element again.  It is not necessary to call initElements() on your class.

Comment: perhaps we should move further discussion to chat, but if you read the suggestions at http://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp it will be more clear to you.  There are many good code samples in Stackoverflow, including one below.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware I think you are missing the concept of PageFactory while you reply. The entire Answer is based on the concept from the URL I mentioned combining with Stackoverflow Answers only. I would request you to share your research on **how do you search for an element which throws `StaleElementReferenceException` again through PageFactory without reinitializing the class?**

Comment: ah...My brain *was* reading "page object model", not "PageFactory model".  This restriction of the PageFactory is probably why I abandoned using it years ago.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209199/how-to-prevent-staleelementreferenceexception-in-pagefactory-in-selenium-c has a less than satisfactory alternate approach to the problem.  DebanjanB, stackoverflow won't let me un-do my downvote unless the answer has been edited, so if you make some minor edit to just trigger that mechanism, I can undo the downvote.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware Glad to hear that. Thanks

Comment: Worked when reinitialized the page class :)

Comment: This is a really bad answer that leads you down the wrong path whilst appearing to fix the issue.  If you haven't used a @CachLookup annotation you don't need to re-initialize the class, you just use the WebElement again and the Java Proxy class that binds the WebElement to the element in the DOM will deal with finding the element again.  Re-initiallizng and then using the WebElement again may appear to work, but it's not because you re-initialized the class, it's because you searched for the element again.

Comment: I tried the same. Only when we reinitialize, the element is being identified. Without reinitialization, I am getting StaleElementException.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known problem with the PageFactory implementation.

If you are unlucky enough for the element to become stale in the instant between the element being found, and then the element being clicked upon, you will get this error.  Unfortunately the PageFactory code does not try to find the element again if it has become stale and it throws an Exception.

I would classify this as a bug with PageFactory, it should auto re-find the element if it ever becomes stale (unless the @CacheLookup annotation is used).

The suggestion to recall initElements isn't going to fix anything, you only need to init the elements once because that binds a Java proxy class to the element in question.  The page factory implementation is supposed to remove the possibility of StaleElementReferenceExceptions (hence why this is a bug)

Answer (score 0):

`Stale element exception` is thrown in two cases

The element is no longer attached to the `DOM`.
The element has been deleted entirely.

When this happen you wrap your code in `try catch block` then you can loop and retry as many times as you need until it succeeds.

```
public void waitForElementPresent(final By by, int timeout){ 
  WebDriverWait wait = (WebDriverWait)new WebDriverWait(driver,timeout)
                  .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class); 
  wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>(){ 
    @Override 
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) { 
      WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(by); 
      return element != null && element.isDisplayed(); 
    } 
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Nice, but the solution specifically asks about dealing with stale element exceptions when using a Page Factory.