# Selenium wait issue

Tags: c#, selenium

I have an input box that pulls an autocomplete list. The list is a little slow to pull, so I need selenium to just wait before pressing the enter key, which will select the first item in the list. here is what I have so far

```
            webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("seg-gl-1")).SendKeys("2");
            webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("seg-gl-1")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

The issue is that selenium is hitting Enter too quickly. I believe I am using the `implicitwait` incorrectly. Can anyone shed some light on my issue?

Comment: To clarify, the implicit wait that you set is used by all subsequent FindElement calls and such. If you set at 10 sec ImplicitWait, that means the webdriver will try to find an element for 10 sec before throwing an ElementNotFoundException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use

```
webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

You are only setting the default ImplicitWait time. If you want to actually perform a wait for, lets say 10sec, you could use

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

Generally you should avoid this type of wait, but I'm guessing that there are javascript/ajax calls performed in the background of your application, and hence you should wait for these to execute before being able to assert the site behaviour (as these calls might update the DOM and such). For further help on that, please refer to my answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45033412/6220192