# stale: either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed

Tags: java, selenium, web, webdriver, geckodriver

I'm trying to login using selenium webdriver (java) in the following website:
 [www.tokopedia.com](http://tokopedia.com).
I succeed to input `email` and `password` but when the code clicks on `login button`, it gives some error. Why is this happening and what should be best solution?

This is my code

```
`private void btnOkActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String filePath = filePathField.getText();
    String emailPath = emailField.getText();
    String passwordPath = passwordField.getText();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Gecko\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver  = new FirefoxDriver();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);

    driver.get("https://www.tokopedia.com");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/header/div/div/div[3]/ul/li[2]/button")).click();
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='iframe-accounts']")));
    WebElement emailLogin = driver.findElement(By.id("inputEmail"));
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement passwordLogin = driver.findElement(By.id("inputPassword"));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Masuk ke Tokopedia')]")).isDisplayed();

  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Masuk ke Tokopedia')]"))).click();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("inputEmail")));            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("inputPassword")));          wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//[contains(text(), 'Masuk ke Tokopedia')]"))).click();
    emailLogin.sendKeys(emailPath);
    passwordLogin.sendKeys(passwordPath);
}                                     

private void emailFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                          

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnOk;
private javax.swing.JTextField emailField;
private javax.swing.JTextField filePathField;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField passwordField;
// End of variables declaration                   
}`
```

This is the error message

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: The element reference of  stale: either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StaleElementReference Exception in PageFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838538/staleelementreference-exception-in-pagefactory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use `sendKeys` directly after finding the element. There will occur problems if you find an element and work with it much later.

Example:

```
WebElement emailLogin = driver.findElement(By.id("inputEmail"));
emailLogin.sendKeys(emailPath);
```

Comment: Thank you brother, you are the life saver :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's the issue with `xpath` you provided for login button. Try this code it helps you:

After

`private void btnOkActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)`

Replace your code with this:

```
String filePath = filePathField.getText();
String emailPath = emailField.getText();
String passwordPath = passwordField.getText();
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Gecko\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver  = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);

driver.get("https://www.tokopedia.com");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/header/div/div/div[3]/ul/li[2]/button")).click();
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='iframe-accounts']")));
WebElement emailLogin = driver.findElement(By.id("inputEmail"));
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement passwordLogin = driver.findElement(By.id("inputPassword"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='global_login_btn']")).isDisplayed();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='global_login_btn']"))).click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("inputEmail")));            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("inputPassword")));          wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//[contains(text(), 'Masuk ke Tokopedia')]"))).click();
emailLogin.sendKeys(emailPath);
passwordLogin.sendKeys(passwordPath);
}
```