# java web crawler: two kinds of Exception while traversing page links using selenium+webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, web-crawler

## Background

The target pages's request is initiated by the js after clicking the link.

So I plan to use selenium + webdriver to simulate the clicking and fetch the page data.(I use chrome driver first for debug)

the parent page is as follows:

[the parent page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrYfX.png)

It is obvious I can't directly get the links' urls from the page.

The following steps go like this:

1. define the list of the links
2. traverse the list element, click the link and get the corresponding page
3. jump to the child page through the page handle, get the target data and go back to the parent-page
4. continue to traverse until the loop over

## Question

According to the above logic, the error occurs at the second time.

The 1st question:

`org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element 
reference: element is not attached to the page document`

My code:

```
int pageIndex = Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mainContent\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tfoot/tr[2]/td/div/ul/li[1]/span/font[3]")).getText());
int pageSize = Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mainContent\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tfoot/tr[2]/td/div/ul/li[1]/span/font[2]")).getText());
while (pageIndex <= pageSize) {
    pageIndex++;
    WebElement tbody = driver.findElement(By.ByXPath.xpath("//*[@id=\"mainContent\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody"));
    List<WebElement> links = tbody.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[class=ng-binding]"));
    for (WebElement link : links) {
        WebDriver window;
        System.out.println("-------------- voucherNo: " + link.getText());
        scrollToElementAndClick(link);
        currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        //get all windows
        Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for (String s : handles) {
            //current page is don't close
            if (s.equals(currentWindow) || s.equals(parentWindow))
                continue;
            else {
                window = driver.switchTo().window(s);
                window.manage().window().maximize();
                window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                window.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                //get all tables
                String pageSource = window.getPageSource();
                String jsonArray = parseDTO(pageSource);
                System.out.println(jsonArray);
                //close the table window
                window.close();
            }
            //swich to current window
            driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);
        }
    }
    // click next page
    if (pageIndex <= pageSize) {
        WebElement nextPage = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mainContent\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tfoot/tr[2]/td/div/ul/li[3]/a"));
        scrollToElementAndClick(nextPage);
        //set next page to current page
        driver = driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandle());
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

I have searched similar questions in the stackoverflow, but the solutions don't work. And I go to the official website to see the error statement

The reason should be when I switch to the subpage, the parent page refreshed. Although the links can be seen on UI, the list of the links, which is defined before, doesn't correspond to the current parent page (I understand this way, if I misunderstand that, please pointed it out).

So I modified the code:

```
while (pageIndex <= pageSize) {
    pageIndex++;
    WebElement tbody = driver.findElement(By.ByXPath.xpath("//*[@id=\"mainContent\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody"));
    List<WebElement> links = tbody.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[class=ng-binding]"));
    int size = links.size();

    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    String href = String.format("//*[@id=\"mainContent\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[%s]/td[2]/a", i);
    WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath(href));
    WebDriver window;
    System.out.println("-------------- voucherNo: " + link.getText());
    scrollToElementAndClick(link);
        currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        //get all windows
        Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for (String s : handles) {
            //current page is don't close
            if (s.equals(currentWindow) || s.equals(parentWindow))
                continue;
            else {
                window = driver.switchTo().window(s);
                window.manage().window().maximize();
                window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                window.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                //get all tables
                String pageSource = window.getPageSource();
                String jsonArray = parseDTO(pageSource);
                System.out.println(jsonArray);
                //close the table window
                window.close();
            }
            //swich to current window
            driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);
        }
    }

    // click next page
    if (pageIndex <= pageSize) {
        WebElement nextPage = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mainContent\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tfoot/tr[2]/td/div/ul/li[3]/a"));
        scrollToElementAndClick(nextPage);
        //set next page to current page
        driver = driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandle());
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

The links' Xpath change regularly:

```
//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a
//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a
//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/a
//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[%s]/td[2]/a
```

Then the 2nd quetion occurs:

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath

Emm..I can't understand why I can't get the webElement. It is right down on the page.

### Addition

well, I notice in that question, the links url can be get from the page. The accepted answer of the question uses a string list to store link href. and use `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open(arguments[0])`, myhref); to execute them. But in my case, I can't get the urls. I need to click the link one by one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: element is not attached to the page document while iterating through a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346047/org-openqa-selenium-staleelementreferenceexception-element-is-not-attached-to-t)

Comment: Thx for commenting. well, I notice that in that question, the links url can be get from the page. The accepted answer use a string list to store link href. and user `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open(arguments[0])", myhref);` to execute them. But in my case, I need to click the link one by one which cause the problem.

Comment: So are you saying the error is occurring when reaching this line `scrollToElementAndClick(link);` on the second loop?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!