# Cant locate the same element after i login

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate elements search bar and menu button after login. 
The html of the element is like

```
<input _ngcontent-c1="" class="rttn-Input-Controller *** **** ng-touched" type="text" placeholder="*******"> 
and  a menu button 
<a class="********" popover="">
                            <span class="********">
                                <svg class="******" height="16" width="16">
                                    <use class="ng-tns-c0-0" xlink:href="#Hamburger" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></use>
                                    <rect class="******"></rect>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                        </a>
```

i can locate search bar before login but after login it says the element is not clickable at this point. 
i have used Actions class still it doesnt click. I am using selenium 3.7(java) on chrome .

Comment: does selenium webdriver have a problem testing angular js applications

Comment: i get stale element reference exception randomly ,also element is not clickable is show.I have tried all the options mentioned in that question.still no luck yet

Comment: For `StaleElementReferenceException` see this [StaleElementReference Exception in PageFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838538/staleelementreference-exception-in-pagefactory/44844879#44844879)