# How to Get the Current URL of an Item in a Loop Using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the current url of an item which is already in a loop

```
def get_financial_info(self):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/chromedriver')

    driver.get("https://www.financialjuice.com")

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='trendWrap']")))
    except TimeoutException:
        driver.quit()

    category_url = [a.get_attribute("href") for a in
                    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='nav navbar-nav']/li[@class='text-uppercase']/a[@href]")]

    for record in category_url:
        driver.get(record)
        item = {}
        url_element = webdriver.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[@class='headline-title']/a[@href]")

        for links in url_element:
            driver.get(links.get_attribute("href"))
            print driver.current_url
```

but i got the first actual link but the code stopped,

http://www.zerohedge.com/news/2017-08-26/brief-history-tail-risk-ltcm-abx-cds-vix?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+zerohedge%2Ffeed+%28zero+hedge+-+on+a+long+enough+timeline%2C+the+survival+rate+for+everyone+drops+to+zero%29

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: headless chrome=62.0.3202.94)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.4.0-101-generic x86_64)
```

i tried studying what happened, i realized that, the webdriver opened the first category, choose the first item and got the actual link and it stopped instead of going back to the previous url, take the second item and get the next link, till the loop ends.

Comment: Does the link open in a new window or an iframe?

Comment: @Danny the link opens in the same window

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StaleElementReference Exception in PageFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838538/staleelementreference-exception-in-pagefactory)

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the same approach for inner `for` loop as you used for the outer one. Replace

```
url_element = webdriver.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[@class='headline-title']/a[@href]")

for links in url_element:
    driver.get(links.get_attribute("href"))
    print driver.current_url
```

with

```
url_element = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in webdriver.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[@class='headline-title']/a")]
for link in url_element:
    driver.get(link)
    print driver.current_url
```

Comment: this worked a bit but keeps timing out, what can i do to avoid that

Comment: @molecules can you clarify what you mean by *timing out*? Where does it time out, and what is the relevant part of the exception?

Comment: i still got unsupported protocol and @mrfreester when the code displays like 10 items, i get time out error

Comment: Share the **exact exception log**

Comment: @Andersson

selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: headless chrome=62.0.3202.94)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.4.0-101-generic x86_64)

I added the code to gist https://gist.github.com/iammiracle/e51e5acf9f3659d84914f5e3a39b27d0

Comment: Hm... This doesn't look like `TimeOutException` or `UnsupportedProtocol`... Can you share **current** exception?

Comment: @Andersson, here is the current issue:

selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: headless chrome=62.0.3202.94)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.4.0-101-generic x86_64)


The timeout, i guess its my network issue, so you can ignore that

Comment: As per provided link your code contains more lines and thus more reasons for errors. Code provided in current SO ticket doesn't contain those lines and so my code can only solve the current problem... I think you should open new ticket regarding new issues

Comment: @Andersson here is the extension of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47569370/error-shown-when-geting-current-url-of-an-item-in-a-loop-after-using-selenium