# How to solve StaleElementReferenceException error

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am doing the automated testing using visual studio. While getting the inner element value it's showing this error.

It's not showing this error all the time but sometimes it's successfully tested.

> OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException occurred
>     HResult=0x80131500
>     Message=stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

I tried to solve this issue, but unfortunately I didn't get any positive result.

Below is my code:

```
public List<CaseListEntry> GetCaseListEntries()
        {
            var CaseGridTrs = CaseListGrid.FindElements(By.XPath(".//tr"));
            var entryList = CaseGridTrs.Select(x =>
            {
                var CaseEntryTds = x.FindElements(By.XPath(".//td"));
                var RegisterDate = CaseEntryTds.ElementAt(1).Text;
                var RegisterNo = CaseEntryTds.ElementAt(3).Text;
                return new CaseListEntry
                {
                    ListNo = CaseEntryTds.ElementAt(0).FindElement(By.XPath(".//a")).Text,
                    RegDate = DateTime.ParseExact(RegisterDate, "dd.MM.yyyy",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    DocumentType = CaseEntryTds.ElementAt(2).Text,
                };
            }).ToList();
            return entryList;
        }
```

I am getting this stale exception error in line 8.I also i tried to use **webdriver.wait** it's still showing the same error.

I also try tried to wait for page to load

```
  var customWait = new WebDriverWait(new SystemClock(), driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
        //ignore the timeout exception
        try
        {
            customWait.Until(CustomExpectedCond.ElementHasClass(LoadingIndicator, "t-icon t-refresh t-loading"));
            customWait.Until(CustomExpectedCond.ElementHasClass(LoadingIndicator, "t-icon t-refresh"));
        }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException) { /*ignore and hope for the best*/ }
    }
```

Comment: From your given code at here, no any code will lead to whole/partial page refresh or reload.  The only possible reason cause stale exeption, I guess should when the GetCaseListEntries() running, the table actually not complete  load totally.  So please try a long sleep before call GetCaseListEntries() to see still meet stale exception or not,  If the sleep can fix the issue, adjust your webdriver.wait to give efficient time to wait the table load

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StaleElementReference Exception in PageFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838538/staleelementreference-exception-in-pagefactory)

Comment: @DebanjanB That post didn't solved my problem

Comment: Which one is `line 8`?

Comment: @DebanjanB  `var RegisterNo = CaseEntryTds.ElementAt(3).Text;`

Comment: Can you show us what `ElementAt` is all about?

Comment: @DebanjanB It's a case table contains four row I'm getting the values from table  using `ElementAt` and store it in string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
public List<CaseListEntry> GetCaseListEntries()
    {
        var CaseGridTrs = CaseListGrid.FindElements(By.XPath(".//tr"));
        var entryList = CaseGridTrs.Select(x =>
        {
            var CaseEntryTds        = x.FindElements(By.XPath(".//td"));

            var ListNoElement       = GetElementOrNull(CaseEntryTds,0);
            var RegisterDateElement = GetElementOrNull(CaseEntryTds,1);
            var DocumentTypeElement = GetElementOrNull(CaseEntryTds,2);
            var RegisterNoElement   = GetElementOrNull(CaseEntryTds,3);


            var RegisterDate        = (RegisterDateElement != null)? RegisterDateElement.Text : "";
            var RegisterNo          = (RegisterNoElement != null)? RegisterNoElement.Text : "";
            var ListNo              = (ListNoElement != null) ? ListNoElement.FindElement(By.XPath(".//a")).Text : "";
            var DocumentType        = (DocumentTypeElement != null) ? DocumentTypeElement.Text : "";
            return new CaseListEntry
            {
                ListNo = ListNo ,
                RegDate = DateTime.ParseExact(RegisterDate, "dd.MM.yyyy",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                DocumentType = DocumentType
            };
        }).ToList();
        return entryList;
    }

public IWebElement GetElementOrNull(IList<IWebElement> CaseEntryTds, int elementAtPosition, int maxSeconds = 1) {
    IWebElement element = null;
    IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(maxSeconds));
    wait.Until(d => {
        try {
            element = CaseEntryTds.ElementAt(elementAtPosition);
            return element.Displayed;
        } catch (WebDriverTimeoutException) {
            return false;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException) {
            return false;
        }
    });
  return element;
```

}

Comment: Can you tell me which line of my code has error and what is the error message?