# I have an error while using Selenium in Python:

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.6

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message:         
    element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

The page is loaded using JavaScript.
On the page, there is a button "show more".
When I click on this button, the data is displayed and the same "show more" button appears. This can continue many times.
I can only click on the first button "show more", but on the following one does not work. I noticed that when the button is out of sight of the screen, then this exception arises!

```
    driver.execute_script ("arguments [0] .scrollIntoView ()" does not work.
      more_info [i] .WebDriverWait (driver, 3) .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "selector")) doesn't work
more_info.location_once_scrolled_into_view
Please help me! i am begginer
my cod: (more_info is driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR)

    def more_foo(more_info):
        more_info.location_once_scrolled_into_view  
        more_info.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StaleElementReference Exception in PageFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838538/staleelementreference-exception-in-pagefactory)

Answer (score 1):

`StaleElement` exception means that due to changes in the DOM, your element is now not attached to the DOM or has been deleted entirely. Read more about the exception [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp).

There is a solution mentioned [here](http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.in/2012/06/staleelementexception.html), which I have implemented and works perfectly. You should try the same - the code is in `.js` though.