# StaleElementReferenceException error using Selenium in python 2.7

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I used this code for Clearing Text Field by Id (using Selenium with python 2.7):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome():
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
search = browser.find_element_by_id('lst-ib')
search.send_keys('Python 2')
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(6)
search.clear()
time.sleep(2)
browser.close()
```

### It gave me the error:

> StaleElementReferenceException            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference:
>   element is not attached to the page document   (Session info:
>   chrome=65.0.3325.181)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315
>   (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.16299 x86_64)

Does anyone know how to fix this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StaleElementReference Exception in PageFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838538/staleelementreference-exception-in-pagefactory)

Answer (score 3):

Once you do `search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` new page is loaded and `search` is no more accessible. You just need to re-define this variable

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome():
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
search = browser.find_element_by_id('lst-ib')
search.send_keys('Python 2')
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(6)
search = browser.find_element_by_id('lst-ib')
search.clear()
time.sleep(2)
browser.close()
```

Also note that using `time.sleep()` is a bad practice. You should look towards [Implicit/Explicit waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#waits)

Comment: Or a better way would be clicking on the element inside a loop.  http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.in/2012/06/staleelementexception.html

Comment: *clicking on the element*? Do you see any clicking in code?

Comment: Keys.Enter (passing the keyboard keys ) is an alternative of finding an element and clicking on it !

Comment: The problem is that OP calls input field object after DOM updated. Can you elaborate how loop can solve this issue?

Comment: you can go through the provided website. That was my understanding.