# Overcoming a StaleElementReferenceException in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, staleelementreferenceexception

**Intention:**

My aim is to scrape football data from whoscored.com. Match pages ([see example here](https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1190514/Live)) contain a timeline view (div id = match-centre-timeline) which has timeline handles in turn (div class = timeline-handle). The handles can be dragged and dropped so to set the timeline to show the match stats for. For example, I'd like to set the lower timeline bound to represent 10 minutes and the upper to represent 30 minutes.

**Setup & Hypothesis:**

I'm using selenium with chrome on OSX 10. The code below moves the lower timeline handle but throws a StaleElementReferenceException. My belief is that the page application becomes confused by the sudden drag and drop.

**Question:**

Is there any way to simulate a slower mouse drag? Is this even the problem? How can this be overcome? Thanks in advance!

**Python 3 code:**

```python
  url = "https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1190514/Live"
    time_to_wait = 20
    wanted_element_id = "match-centre-timeline"

    opts = ChromeOptions()
    opts.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    opts.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    opts.add_argument("disable-notifications")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/david/Dropbox/Code/gitCode/driver/chromedriver", chrome_options=opts)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(time_to_wait)

    example_loaded = bool(True)
    while example_loaded:
        try:
            driver.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(driver,time_to_wait).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, wanted_element_id)))
            print("[STATUS]\tFound " + wanted_element_id + ".") 
            example_loaded= False
        except TimeoutException:
            print("[WARNING]\tCannot find the " + wanted_element_id + ". Retrying.")

    tlh = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='match-centre-timeline']/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span")
    tuh = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='match-centre-timeline']/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span")

    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", tlh)    

    actions = ActionChains(driver)

    # move to the lower timeline handle
    actions.move_to_element(tlh)
    actions.perform()

    print("[NOTE]\t\tLower handle stats: x:{}, y:{} and h:{}px, w:{}px.".format( tlh.location['x'], tlh.location['y'], tlh.size['height'], tlh.size['width'] ))
    print("[NOTE]\t\tUpper handle stats: x:{}, y:{} and h:{}px, w:{}px.".format( tuh.location['x'], tuh.location['y'], tuh.size['height'], tuh.size['width'] ))

    # let's click on the lower timeline handle
    try:
        actions.click_and_hold(tlh)
        actions.drag_and_drop_by_offset(tlh, 100, 0)
        actions.perform()
    print("[NOTE]\t\tLower handle stats: x:{}, y:{} and h:{}px, w:{}px.".format( tlh.location['x'], tlh.location['y'], tlh.size['height'], tlh.size['width'] ))
    print("[NOTE]\t\tUpper handle stats: x:{}, y:{} and h:{}px, w:{}px.".format( tuh.location['x'], tuh.location['y'], tuh.size['height'], tuh.size['width'] ))
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        print("[WARN]\tThrew and caught a StaleElementReferenceException.")
```

**Console Error:**

```
[STATUS]    Found match-centre-timeline.
[NOTE]      Lower handle stats: x:118, y:1341 and h:41px, w:19px.
[NOTE]      Upper handle stats: x:869, y:1341 and h:41px, w:30px.
[WARN]  Threw and caught a StaleElementReferenceException
See anything?
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "whoscored-scrape.py", line 442, in <module>
print("[NOTE]\t\tLower handle stats: x:{}, y:{} and h:{}px, w:{}px.".format( tlh.location['x'], tlh.location['y'], tlh.size['height'], tlh.size['width'] ))
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 404, in location
old_loc = self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_LOCATION)['value']
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 493, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
(Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)(Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540469 (1881fd7f8641508feb5166b7cae561d87723cfa8),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
```

**Supporting imagery:**

- [Default match centre section view (unaltered timelines)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc4Wo.png)
- [Match centre view once the lower timeline is manually adjusted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coqQP.png)
- [The broken match centre view in after running the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjqZa.png)

Comment: Can you provide the error message as well.
Usually Stale element error occurs, when you try to access the element reference which you taken before the page dom gets updated. simple fix for this is which ever the elements you are accessing (in the line where the exception occurred), take the reference again by calling driver.findelementBy method before you perform some action on those element. this will solve your issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StaleElementReference Exception in PageFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838538/staleelementreference-exception-in-pagefactory)

Comment: Hi @AuroSarma thanks for commenting.

I've attached the console output and some supporting imagery. As you can hopefully see in the third screenshot, the timeline control appears to be disconnected from the DOM itself as a result of executing actions.drag_and_drop_by_offset(). I suspect this is because it's too sudden; a human user would drag and scroll over time whereas perhaps the driver does so instantly(?). Therefore even if I created a new reference to 'tlh' in the code, a StaleElementReferenceException would still be thrown. This is the problem I'm seeking advice on.

Comment: @DebanjanB please see the comment above. Thank you.