# Why can't I reuse WebElement object instances in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to selenium webdriver, and I am working on testing a form using java and I encounter an issue of not being able to reuse instances of WebElement

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("number"));
element.sendKeys("4");

// submit form this clears the element text box

element.sendKeys("7");  // this won't type 7 in the box?
```

But this works:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("number"));
element.sendKeys("4");

// submit form this clears the element text box

WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.name("number"));
element2.sendKeys("7");
```

Doesn't seem to make sense to have to instantiate another webelement object. Please give me insight, thanks.

Comment: What happens in the first case? What exception do you get?

Answer (score 0):

When you **submit form** which inturn **clears the element text box** essentially means the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) have refreshed and possibly either/all of the actions have happened :

- Some new elements have been added to the *DOM*.
- Some old elements are no more present in the *DOM*.
- Some *DOM* element's attributes may have changed.
- Inshort the *HTML DOM* have changed.

In this cases if you try to do :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("number"));
element.sendKeys("4");
// submit form this clears the element text box
element.sendKeys("7");
```

Selenium will complain about [StaleElementReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838538/staleelementreference-exception-in-pagefactory/44844879#44844879)

Hence the solution is to search the desired element again afresh and then invoke the `sendKeys()` method as follows :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("number"));
element.sendKeys("4");
// submit form this clears the element text box
WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.name("number"));
element2.sendKeys("7");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Page Factory concept in Page Object Model.
Refer: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-pattern-model-page-factory/

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("number"));  
element.sendKeys("4");  

// submit form this clears the element text box  

driver.navigate().refresh();  
(new WebDriverWait(driver,10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("number")));

element.sendKeys("7");
```