# POP function for Present&enabled checking in selenium (Java)

Tags: java, selenium

I working in selenium and now for checking visibility of element i use following wait until:

```
@FindBy (css=".delete-basket-modal-btn") WebElement deleteItemFromBasketCancelButton;
public void clickDeleteItemFromBasketCancelButton() throws InterruptedException {   
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(deleteItemFromBasketCancelButton));
    deleteItemFromBasketCancelButton.click();
}
```

that's not good idea, this function is not checking for presence of element, so sometimes i get 'stale element reference element is not attached to the page document'

Now i trying to create universal function which will be inherited by all of mine page object class. In this function i need checking (5 sec) for presence, enability, clickability and visibilty of WebElement passed in argument.

For this moment i have new function below, but i dont know that is good approach for my problem

```
public void verifyElement(WebElement element) throws InterruptedException {
    boolean isPresent = false;


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        try {
            if (element != null) {
                isPresent = true;               // metoda do czekania na element  
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

    }
    Assert.assertTrue(isPresent, "\"" + element + "\" is not present.");


    boolean isEnabled = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        try {
            if (element.isEnabled()==true) {
                isEnabled = true;
                break;
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
    Assert.assertTrue(isEnabled, "\"" + element + "\" is not enabled.");
```

}

Do you have any suggestion or similar problem for this issue?

Comment: Can you help us to decipher what exactly you mean by **POP**?

Comment: page object pattern :)

Comment: Check this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838538/staleelementreference-exception-in-pagefactory

Answer (score 0):

`StaleElementReferenceException` doesn't (necessarily) mean the element is not present, it means the DOM had changed/refreshed since the element was located, so the element reference which the `driver` holds is no longer valid. This is a disadvantage of using `PageFactory` model.

The solution is to locate the element just before the click operation, however this will break the consistency of the page object. Instead of using `FindBy` send `By` to the method and locate the element there

```
public void clickDeleteItemFromBasketCancelButton(By by) throws InterruptedException {
    WebElement deleteItemFromBasketCancelButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));
    deleteItemFromBasketCancelButton.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first written code is enough. To overcome stale element exception write code in try/catch block and use `ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(deleteItemFromBasketCancelButton)` for  presence, enability, clickability and visibilty (for any type of operation).

Try below one, hope it's help for you.

```
try{
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(deleteItemFromBasketCancelButton));
    deleteItemFromBasketCancelButton.click();
}
catch(Exception e){
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(deleteItemFromBasketCancelButton)))
deleteItemFromBasketCancelButton.click();
}
```