# How to add explicit wait in PageFactory in PageObjectModel?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, webdriverwait, page-factory

I have added hardcode wait `thread.sleep()` in my below code. How to use explicit wait. I want to wait till "username"  WebElement appear. My program is working perfectly. I have already written testcases.

```
package com.pol.zoho.PageObjects;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class ZohoLoginPage {

WebDriver driver;
public ZohoLoginPage(WebDriver driver)
{
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

@FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='lid']")
public WebElement email;

@FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='pwd']")
public WebElement password;

@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='signin_submit']")
public WebElement signin;

public void doLogin(String username,String userpassword)
{
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    email.sendKeys(username);
    password.sendKeys(userpassword);
    signin.click();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using **PageFactory** in **PageObjectModel** if you expect the element to be loaded through some [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) and it might not be present on the page already you can use the *Explicit Wait* support with a normal locator factory as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  package com.pol.zoho.PageObjects;
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class ZohoLoginPage {

      WebDriver driver;
      public ZohoLoginPage(WebDriver driver)
      {
          PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
      }

      @FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='lid']")
      public WebElement email;

      @FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='pwd']")
      public WebElement password;

      @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='signin_submit']")
      public WebElement signin;

      public void doLogin(String username,String userpassword)
      {
          WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ZohoLoginPage.getWebElement()));
          email.sendKeys(username);
          password.sendKeys(userpassword);
          signin.click();
      }

      public WebElement getWebElement()
      {
          return email;
      }

  }
  ```

You can find a detailed discussion in [How to use explicit waits with PageFactory fields and the PageObject pattern](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/7AGczMaV578)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1- You can use implicity wait while initializing the driver.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

2- Use explicty wait for the username field only:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
WebElement element = wait.until(
                    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(By.id(identifier)));
```

Comment: WebElement element = wait.until(
                    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(By.id(identifier))); this is not the way to do in pageobject model. it will throw error

Comment: what error?
or you can also use `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(email)`