# Use visibilityOfElementLocated with pagefactory

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, pageobjects, page-factory

I'm writing automated scripts using page factory and I want to use visibilityOfElementLocated with page factory instead of visibilityOf 
I tried to use visibilityOf but some times it not work with my element

the problem here that visibilityOfElementLocated take By parameter, and I have WebElment

```
@FindBy(id = "test")
WebElement locator;
```

Comment: Why don't you use `visibilityOf` ? [javadoc](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-)

Comment: I want to check if the element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. however the `visibilityOf` method check the visiblity of the element only

Answer (score 1):

You can't use it directly with `@FindBy`, but you can call it from a method that will run before `PageFactory.initElements`

```
public abstract class BasePage {

    protected WebDriverWait wait;

    public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        assertInPage();
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); 
    }

    public abstract void assertInPage();
}

public class DerivedPage extends BasePage {

    @FindBy(id = "test")
    WebElement locator;

    public DerivedPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    @Override
    public void assertInPage() {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("test")));
    }
}
```

`assertInPage()` in `DerivedPage` will be executed right before `PageFactory.initElements`.

Answer (score 0):

### visibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)

[`visibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) takes a __By locator_ as an argument and is the expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible.

---

### visibilityOf(WebElement element)

[`visibilityOf(WebElement element)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) takes an *WebElement* as an argument and is the expectation for checking that an element, known to be present on the DOM of a page, is visible.

---

When using *PageFactory* in *PageObjectModel* if you expect the element to be dynamic and loaded through some [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) and might not be present on the page already you can use the *Explicit Wait* support with a normal locator factory as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class TestPage {

      WebDriver driver;

      //constructor
      public TestPage(WebDriver driver)
      {
          PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
      }

      //Locator Strategy
      @FindBy(id = "test")
      WebElement locator;

      //Test Method
      public void testMethod()
      {
          WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(TestPage.getWebElement()));
          //perform your desired action here e.g element.click()
      }

      public WebElement getWebElement()
      {
          return locator;
      }

  }
  ```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How to add explicit wait in PageFactory in PageObjectModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158166/how-to-add-explicit-wait-in-pagefactory-in-pageobjectmodel/54177337#54177337)

Comment: What does this answer offer that Guy's didn't yesterday?