# How to wait for img src attribute to change using Selenium and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

let's say I have an element:

```
<div>
 <img src='src1'>
</div>
```

and after some time `src` changes to some other link
so how to I wait for it (or any property in general) to change?

maybe something like this:

```
await driver.wait(until.elementAttributeChanged(el,'src'),3000);
```

Comment: Do you know what will be the expected value once it's changed to some other link ?

Comment: @cruisepandey no i will have no idea what the new src will be

Comment: Would it change multiple times or just once ?

Comment: @cruisepandey it might change multiple times but if I can figure out how to detect it when it's changed once, I can figure out how to detect multiple changes

Comment: Do you know the initial attribute value?

Comment: @Prophet yes I know src1, but it would be better if a solution could handle unkown values as well :)

Comment: If you know the initial value then you can have a condition that if that src does not meet the value that you've, then it must have been changed, make any sense to you ?

Comment: @cruisepandey yes but I don't know after what amount of time the value will be changed

Comment: @cakelover : We can have a loop for 30 seconds or so.. to check if the value has been changed or not.

Comment: @cruisepandey i would have done that but it seems inefficient, is there a more spontaneous solution?

Comment: @cakelover : None that I am aware of, with the pre-conditions that you've. Good luck !

Comment: I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but after some google search i found this link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver. See if you can use it.

Comment: @cakelover unknown value can be passed as a parameter, and the locator can be built dynamically depending on it. it's not a problem at all. In case the value is unique. I.e. no more elements will have this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To wait for the *src* attribute of the `<img>` to change using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) you can use the following [until](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html) condition:

- [*`stalenessOf( element )`*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.js#L280): Creates a condition that will wait for the given element to become stale. An element is considered stale once it is removed from the DOM, or a new page has loaded.

  ```
  let element = await driver.findElement(By.id('elementID'));
  await driver.wait(until.stalenessOf(element),1000);
  ```

Comment: I'm a little confused about the definition of stale, does modifying the src remove the element out of the DOM? if so then does that end the waiting ? could u elaborate a little on how this works?

Comment: [_Staleness_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838538/staleelementreference-exception-in-pagefactory/44844879#44844879) indicates that the previous reference of the element is now stale and the element reference is no longer present on the DOM of the page, i.e. The (previous) element has been deleted by a JavaScript or AjaxCall and is replaced by a (new) element with the same ID or other attributes.

Comment: wait so does changing an attribute replace the element with a new one?

Comment: @cakelover yes, of-coarse

Answer (score 0):

Just to make DebanjanB's answer more precise.
Since we want to indicate the changing of `src` attribute value of some element, we can use locator based on the value of `src` attribute of that element. So the code can be something like this:

```
let element = await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//img[@src="src1"]'));
await driver.wait(until.stalenessOf(element),1000);
```